# Sticky notes in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making some kind of sticky notes in javascript for school project. I've already made button, which allows to add notes (they're now just div's) without any text. I can delete them, by pressing red div on each note. There is also counter which counts actual number of notes on the screen, and another one, which counts all notes, since first one. I have to do another 3 things, which are:

1. Changing size of each note by pressing green div and holding it pressed while moving the mouse.
2. Opening a Tinymce editor by pressing a yellow div. Well, opener works, but I need to close it, by pressing red div and by pressing green div I need to save written text in note, which opened editor.
3. Choosing multiple notes, like some files in Windows on the desktop, and moving it. Moving a group of notes.

I hope someone will help me :/ I really need this.

My current code:

```
var cnt = 0;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var xx = 0;
var yy = 0;
var counter = 0;
var ilosc = 0;
var dragging = false;
var klikd = false;

document.addEventListener("onload",Load());

function Load(){
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "modern"
    });
}

function adder(){
    //alert("thall");

    var paper = document.createElement("div");
    var paperS = document.createElement("div");
    var paperX = document.createElement("div");
    var paperW = document.createElement("div");
    paper.setAttribute("id","kartka"+counter);
    paper.setAttribute("onmousedown","itsyourmoove(this,event)");
    paper.setAttribute("onmouseup","nara(this)");
    paper.setAttribute("onmouseleave","elo(this)");
    paperX.setAttribute("id","deleter");
    paperX.setAttribute("onclick","killmepls("+counter+")");
    paperS.setAttribute("id","size");
    paperS.setAttribute("onmousedown","sizechanger(this,event)");
    paperW.setAttribute("id","write");
    paperW.setAttribute("onclick","writeTxt("+counter+")");
    paper.setAttribute("class","kartka");
    paper.appendChild(paperX);
    paper.appendChild(paperS);
    paper.appendChild(paperW);
    document.body.appendChild(paper);
    counter++;
    ilosc++;

    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Przebieg = " + counter + "<br>" + "Ilosc kartek na tablicy: " + ilosc;
}


function itsyourmoove(e,event)
{
    cnt++;
    e.style.zIndex = cnt; //The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
    x = event.clientX;
    y  = event.clientY;
    xx = e.style.left;
    yy = e.style.top;
    xx = xx.slice(0,xx.search("px"));
    yy = yy.slice(0,yy.search("px"));
    x = x - xx;
    y = y - yy;

    e.setAttribute("onmousemove","move(this,event)");

}

function writeTxt(){
    //alert("meme");
    var tiny = document.getElementById("editor");
    tiny.style.visibility = "visible";
    var tindiv = document.getElementById("tiny");
    tindiv.style.visibility = "visible";

}

function killmepls(e){
    //e.parentElement.id="USUNTO";
    //var iks = document.getElementById("USUNTO");
    //iks.parentNode.removeChild(iks);
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("kartka"+e));
    ilosc--;
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Przebieg = " + counter + "<br>" + "Ilosc kartek na tablicy: " + ilosc;


}

function move(e,event){
    e.style.top = event.clientY - y + "px";
    e.style.left = event.clientX - x + "px";
}

function elo(e){
    e.setAttribute("onmousemove","nothing()");
}

function nara(e){
    e.setAttribute("onmousemove","nothing()");
}
function nothing(){
    console.log("nice meme");
    //alert("you've got memed");
}

function sizechanger(e, event){

    e.setAttribute("onmousedown","changeWidthHeight(this,event)");
    klikd = true;
}

function changeWidthHeight(e,event){
    if(klikd = true){
    p = e.parentElement;
    event.clientY = y;
    event.clientX = x;
    p.style.width = (e.clientX - parseInt(getComputedStyle(p).left)) + "px";
    p.style.height = (e.clientX - parseInt(getComputedStyle(p).top)) + "px";
    }else{
        nothing();
        }
}
var close = document.getElementById("exit");

    close.onmousedown = function () {
        var tiny = document.getElementById("ed");
        tiny.style.visibility = "hidden";
        var tindiv = document.getElementById("tiny");
        tindiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
        var my_editor_id = 'content';
        tinymce.get(my_editor_id).setContent(' '); 
    }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OhaTPf58wVHwpLrPq8zg?p=preview

Comment: Do you really expect us to download a random zip file from what looks like an iffy website? Please make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or use the default code snippet functionality.

Comment: Okay, but I am using extra hm library, which is Tinymce, and I can't add it in JSFiddle :/

Comment: btw, the kind of things you're talking about doing sound like drag-and-drop behavior, which is not easy.  You're not doing drag-and-drop in pure JavaScript are you?  Because that's a huge waste of time.  You should be using a library.

Comment: Of course you can use TimyMCE. Just include scripts and set up demo. Here is a starting demo for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/nUboXaOImy0nI575qXbf?p=info

Comment: if you want to use a library then this is what you want, https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula

Comment: I have used YUI for drag-and-drop with success.

Comment: but the problem is, that i have to do this only in pure javascript, with only Tinymce addition ;/

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I would never attempt to implement drag-and-drop myself in pure javascript and I'm not the person to help you.  If you are allowed to, perhaps you can select multiple notes using check boxes?  Your #1 sounds very much like drag-and-drop, though.  It can be done.  It'll just be tedious.

Comment: using libraries is great, your instructor is making oyu reinvent the wheel a bit to learn...So you are going to need to figure it out...that's kinda the point of the project I bet...if he just wanted you to have a drag and drop sticky note program on your computer he would have sent you a link to  a website to download one...

Comment: It's like having students reinvent science before discovering new science.  It's a waste of time and energy.

Comment: I know, I know, but I can't change it :/